# Unable to connect to router/modem using Ethernet but can connect using Wireless

Tags: router, wireless-router, modem, broadband

I can connect to my routers admin 192.168.1.1 using my laptops wireless connection, but I cannot connect using the LAN ports. Can this mean that the LAN ports are defective? I've tried everything from Automatically assign IP address to Static Addresses.

When I plug the cable into the routers LAN port and to my Laptop, my laptop shows network cable unplugged.

What can be done to solve this?

My Modem us a UTStarcom, model WA3002G4

[image]

Comment: Has the connection ever worked?  Have you tried another cable?  Another device/PC?

Comment: The connection used to work. I used to connect this to my desktop before. Now its acting funny. It was set aside for 4 months. Unused.

Comment: Try a different cable.  Verify the port on the computer works.  one way you can verify, if you can get to the router's configuration page, both ports are working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't use it in a while, the connectors might be oxidized and don't make contact anymore, try gently scrapping them with a screwdriver.

Other less dramatic causes might be as simple as the Ethernet cable being damaged so you should try with one that you know for sure works, or maybe the laptop's ethernet interface has the issue.

Comment: I'll try all this.